# Data will not store inside excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I wish there will be a pop out box when ComboBox2 is equal to NiPd, then ComboBox6 value must be fall in the range that I set.
If it fall out from the range, it will show a pop out message.
Others than that, my code also will check on the TextBox8 value when the value is over 3.2, it will show a pop out message as well.

But I have compile all my code, when it comes to the textbox8 is less than 3.2, it will not able to store the data inside the excel sheet when the commandbutton1 is being clicked.

Others than that, I also find out that if I choose to retype the value in TextBox8, it will auto store my data which is what I don't want it to happen.
I wish that, it will only store the data which is I re-type.
I have stuck on this and I have totally no idea on what was wrong inside my code.

My code as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Overall").Activate

Dim m As Variant, RequiredRange As Variant
Dim msg As Integer

RequiredRange1 = Array("30S", "30A", "40S")
RequiredRange2 = Array("10A", "15S", "15A", "20S")
RequiredRange3 = Array("30S", "30A", "40S")

If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "NiPd" Then
m = Application.Match(ComboBox6.Value, RequiredRange1, False)
If IsError(m) Then

msg = MsgBox("Stabilizer Reading:" & ComboBox6.Value & Chr(10) & _
 "Selection Value Out Of Range" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
 "Do You Want To Continue With Submission?", 36, "Warning")

If msg = 7 Then Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus: Exit Sub
End If
End If


 If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "NiAu" Then

m = Application.Match(ComboBox6.Value, RequiredRange2, False)
If IsError(m) Then

msg = MsgBox("Stabilizer Reading:" & ComboBox6.Value & Chr(10) & _
 "Selection Value Out Of Range" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
 "Do You Want To Continue With Submission?", 36, "Warning")

If msg = 7 Then Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus: Exit Sub
End If
End If

If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "NiPdAu" Then

m = Application.Match(ComboBox6.Value, RequiredRange3, False)
If IsError(m) Then

msg = MsgBox("Stabilizer Reading:" & ComboBox6.Value & Chr(10) & _
 "Selection Value Out Of Range" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
 "Do You Want To Continue With Submission?", 36, "Warning")

If msg = 7 Then Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus: Exit Sub
End If
End If

With Me
If Len(.ComboBox1.Value) * Len(.TextBox1.Value) * Len(.ComboBox7.Value) * Len(.ComboBox3.Value) * Len(.ComboBox2.Value) * Len(.TextBox2.Value) * Len(.TextBox3.Value) * Len(.ComboBox4.Value) * Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value) * Len(.TextBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox6.Value) * Len(.ComboBox6.Value) * Len(.TextBox7.Value) * Len(.TextBox8.Value) * Len(.TextBox9.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit"
Else

    If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) > 3 Then
        If MsgBox("Plating Rate below than 3.0 um, Kindly stop production and use another Ni Bath" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                  "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Exceeds") = vbNo Then

            MsgBox "user to re-type the value in TextBox8.", vbInformation, "Warning"

    If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) = 3.2 Then
        If MsgBox("Plating Rate below than 3.2 um , Standby the next Ni bath and start heat up to 65°" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                  "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Exceeds") = vbNo Then

            MsgBox "user to re-type the value in TextBox8.", vbInformation, "Warning"


            Exit Sub
         End If
                  End If
     End If

    eRow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    Cells(eRow, 5).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = ComboBox7.Text
    Cells(eRow, 6).Value = ComboBox3.Text
    Cells(eRow, 15).Value = ComboBox2.Text
    Cells(eRow, 17).Value = TextBox2.Text
    Cells(eRow, 18).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Cells(eRow, 9).Value = ComboBox4.Text
    Cells(eRow, 11).Value = ComboBox5.Text
    Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Text
    Cells(eRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text
    Cells(eRow, 14).Value = TextBox6.Text
    Cells(eRow, 16).Value = ComboBox6.Text
    Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox7.Text
    Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox8.Text
    Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox9.Text
     End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You have dumped 94 lines of code. ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid writing code like `If msg = 7 Then Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus: Exit Sub` because it is too hard to see what is happening. Instead split the lines of code:

```
If msg = 7 Then 
    Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You should also always indent the code inside an If ... End If block because it makes it much easier to see how the code has been grouped.

If you re-organise your code like below, it is much easier to see the groupings. You can also use other procedures to keep lots of code separated. I've added the `UpdateTheSheet` proc.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Overall").Activate

    Dim m As Variant, RequiredRange As Variant
    Dim msg As Integer

    RequiredRange1 = Array("30S", "30A", "40S")
    RequiredRange2 = Array("10A", "15S", "15A", "20S")
    RequiredRange3 = Array("30S", "30A", "40S")

    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "NiPd" Then
        m = Application.Match(ComboBox6.Value, RequiredRange1, False)
        If IsError(m) Then
            msg = MsgBox("Stabilizer Reading:" & ComboBox6.Value & Chr(10) & _
             "Selection Value Out Of Range" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
             "Do You Want To Continue With Submission?", 36, "Warning")
            If msg = 7 Then
                Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "NiAu" Then
        m = Application.Match(ComboBox6.Value, RequiredRange2, False)
        If IsError(m) Then
            msg = MsgBox("Stabilizer Reading:" & ComboBox6.Value & Chr(10) & _
                "Selection Value Out Of Range" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                "Do You Want To Continue With Submission?", 36, "Warning")

            If msg = 7 Then
                Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "NiPdAu" Then
        m = Application.Match(ComboBox6.Value, RequiredRange3, False)
        If IsError(m) Then
            msg = MsgBox("Stabilizer Reading:" & ComboBox6.Value & Chr(10) & _
                "Selection Value Out Of Range" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                "Do You Want To Continue With Submission?", 36, "Warning")
            If msg = 7 Then
                Me.ComboBox6.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If

    With Me
        If Len(.ComboBox1.Value) * Len(.TextBox1.Value) * Len(.ComboBox7.Value) * Len(.ComboBox3.Value) * Len(.ComboBox2.Value) * Len(.TextBox2.Value) * Len(.TextBox3.Value) * Len(.ComboBox4.Value) * Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value) * Len(.TextBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox6.Value) * Len(.ComboBox6.Value) * Len(.TextBox7.Value) * Len(.TextBox8.Value) * Len(.TextBox9.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit"
        Else
            If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) > 3 Then
                If MsgBox("Plating Rate below than 3.0 um, Kindly stop production and use another Ni Bath" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                          "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Exceeds") = vbNo Then

                    MsgBox "user to re-type the value in TextBox8.", vbInformation, "Warning"

                    If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) = 3.2 Then
                        If MsgBox("Plating Rate below than 3.2 um , Standby the next Ni bath and start heat up to 65°" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                                  "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Exceeds") = vbNo Then

                            MsgBox "user to re-type the value in TextBox8.", vbInformation, "Warning"
                            Exit Sub
                         End If
                    End If
                 End If

                eRow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                UpdateTheSheet
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTheSheet()
    ' Writes the values from user input to the worksheet
    Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    Cells(eRow, 5).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = ComboBox7.Text
    Cells(eRow, 6).Value = ComboBox3.Text
    Cells(eRow, 15).Value = ComboBox2.Text
    Cells(eRow, 17).Value = TextBox2.Text
    Cells(eRow, 18).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Cells(eRow, 9).Value = ComboBox4.Text
    Cells(eRow, 11).Value = ComboBox5.Text
    Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Text
    Cells(eRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text
    Cells(eRow, 14).Value = TextBox6.Text
    Cells(eRow, 16).Value = ComboBox6.Text
    Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox7.Text
    Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox8.Text
    Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox9.Text
End Sub
```